# Error 500 when retrieving empty GET parameter

Tags: python, django

My code looks like this :

```
def rssfeeds(request):
    reqdata = request.GET['url']
    if reqdata == '':
        d = "https://github.com/rudrasingh99.private.atom?token=MYPRIVATETOKEN"
        data = []
        for post in d.entries:
             data.append(post.title)
        my_context = {
        "my_list" : data,
        }
    else:
        d = feedparser.parse(reqdata)
        data = []
        for post in d.entries:
             data.append(post.title)
        my_context = {
        "my_list" : data,
        }
    return render(request,"base.html",my_context)

def home_view(request):
    return render(request,"index.html",{})
```

while whenever i try with empty url parameter it gives me 500 error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: @HenryWoody Server Error (500)

Comment: what about from Django itself, like in the console that is running `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: You should include the error log in the question. If you don't log errors, then you should start doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you a 500 error because the `request.GET` is a dictionary. It's really a `KeyError` under the hood; set `DEBUG=True` to find this.

Use `.get` to get terms with default values and handle appropriately.

`reqdata = request.GET.get('url', 'mydefaultvalue')`

If `url` is required for the page to load properly, maybe consider returning a human readable error?

```
reqdata = request.GET.get('url', '')
if reqdata == '':
    return HttpResponse("Specify a url!")
```